# How to use data from Azure Active Directory in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I want to use the Azure Active Directory for identity. I searched for a solution how to "integrate" it into a Vue.js single page application -> result was the oidc-client-js.
Now I am looking for a solution how to save sensible information about the user in a cookie and not in local or session storage of the browser.

Many thanks for the support in advance!
I'am grateful for alternatives to oidc.

Comment: Hello Julius, Did you get a chance to look at - https://github.com/survirtual/vue-adal ?

Comment: Yes, I am still looking for help. All libraries which I found store sensible data in local or session storage. I'am looking for a way to store the data in a cookie and to activate HttpOnly. ... Maybe the authentication should be implemented in the web api and not in single page application part. - Thanks for support!

Comment: Thank You for the detailed input, let me check this and get back to you.